# Automatic highlight code in a wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-highlighting

I've a self installed wordpres blog full of Python snippets and I'd like to have them highlighted (source code colored). I tried to install a couple of plugins like [wp-syntax](http://wordpress.org/tags/wp-syntax) and [Jquery.Syntax](http://wordpress.org/tags/wp-syntax) but they require me to edit all my posts adding some attrs to the pre tags.

How can I hack into the plugins or wordpress in other to apply the plugins to all the pre tags?

Comment: See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple plugin that will register a "filter". This filter will apply to all your posts :

```
function enhance_pre_tag_filter($content){
    $content = preg_replace( '/<pre>/', '<pre python_tags>', $content );
    return $content;
}

foreach(array('the_content','the_title','comment_text') as $filter)
    add_filter($filter, 'enhance_pre_tag_filter',9);
```

Comment: How I ensure to run it before the other plugin? The other one use 0 as last parameter for add_filter.

Comment: I tried to activate that as a plugin and got a "The plugin does not have a valid header." message.

Comment: To ensure this filter is executed before, it must have a lower priority. If the other plugin filter has a 0 (highest) priority, you have to change it.

The code I gave you is only the main part of the plugin. To be valid, a WP plugin must have a valid header (PHP comments). See the WordPress codex (article http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will first need to check whether you are installing a theme or a plugin. Sometimes when you install a `.zip` file of a theme, it goes in as a plugin. This can cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to install a plugin such as [Prismatic](https://wordpress.org/plugins/prismatic/). It's free to use and very simple for highlighting code in WordPress posts and pages.

Once you have the plugin installed and activated, then set it to use one of the libraries from the plugin settings.

Then just simply do a database Find and Replace to add `class="language-python"` to all of your `<pre>` tags. Now you should see all of your Python code will be perfectly highlighted. Alternatively you could also just manually go and add that class to all your `<pre>` tags.